# Passing a string to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question. How do I pass a string to a javascript function and make a popup box alert containing the contents of that string? Here's what I have:

The test.html.erb file.

```
<%= link_to 'Test','#', onclick: 'test(helloworld)', class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
```

Here's the test.js file:

```
function test(name){
     alert(name);
}
```

However, when I click on the "Test" link that gets generated, "helloworld" doesn't pop up. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `helloworld` in quotes when you pass it in:

```
onclick: 'test("helloworld")'
```

I imagine there is some kind of error in the console as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 5):

```
onclick: 'test(helloworld)'
```

would pass the variable named helloworld to the function. Instead, you want to pass a string literal, like:

```
onclick: 'test("helloworld")'
```